# How do I access the iddoFeed node and fetch all information?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
firebase.database().ref('feeds').once('value').then((snapshot) => {

        let feeds = []

        snapshot.forEach((childItem) => {
            feeds.push({
                key: childItem.key,
                id: childItem.val().id_user,
                id_user: childItem.val().id_user,
                url: childItem.val().url,
                date_posted: childItem.val().date_posted,
                name: childItem.val().name,
                avatar:childItem.val().avatar,
                like_count: childItem.val().like_count,
                is_liked: childItem.val().is_liked,
                //comments: childItem.comments
            })
        })
```

Comment: Next time please post a more clear question and explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you just need to destructure the iddoFeed object.. Your question is unclear but I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
let feeds = []

    snapshot.forEach((childItem) => {
        feeds.push({
            key: childItem.key,
            id: childItem.val().iddoFeed.id_user,
            id_user: childItem.val().iddoFeed.id_user,
            url: childItem.val().iddoFeed.url,
            date_posted: childItem.val().iddoFeed.date_posted,
            name: childItem.val().iddoFeed.name,
            avatar:childItem.val().iddoFeed.avatar,
            like_count: childItem.val().iddoFeed.like_count,
            is_liked: childItem.val().iddoFeed.is_liked,

        })
    })
```

Comment: The iddoFeed will be different, the image is just a wraparound.
When I do the search it accesses the first node, but I do not have access inside the iddoFeed